# First item in collection view not preselected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

i am trying to preselect a first collection view cell on load but item is not preselected on load

Code i used to preselect collection view cell is provided below

```
MenuBar.m // Type  UIView <UICollectionViewDelegate ,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

...

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];

UICollectionView *collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];

....
  // below code in   -(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame

 NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];

    [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath
                                 animated:false
                           scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];




....
// below code in   -(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

Comment: why you call collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath? Did you implement this method inside your class?

Answer (score 0):

Implement this method `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath` inside your class

Preselecting is par of logic which should be controlling by `UIViewController`
Provide method for preselecting to your custom view:
`.h` file:

```
- (void)preselectCellAt:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

your `.m` file:

```
- (void)preselectCellAt:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                     animated:false 
                     scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
      [self collectionView:collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    }
```

Your superview `ViewController` where this `UIView` is initialized:

```
- (Void)viewDidiAppear {
  [super viewDidiAppear];
  NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
  [self.customView preselectCellAt:selectedIndexPath];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply . The type of class where UICollectionView defined is UIView . i get error when i add above code . error is 'No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'viewDidAppear:''

Comment: Replaced method with willMoveToSuperview

Comment: When are you providing data to your collection view?

Comment: i have updated code in question. [collectionView
         registerClass:MenuCell.self
         forCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.cell];

        self.menuCellImages = [NSArray
                               arrayWithObjects:
                               @"play",
                               @"pause",
                               @"fire",
                               @"wifi",
                               nil];

Comment: i have tried updated code but still first cell not selected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153638/discussion-between-yerkebulan-abildin-and-ios).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `selectedBackgroundView` in your `UICollectionViewCell`.

For example, if you want your `UICollectionViewCell` be green when selected, you have to write such code in your `UICollectionViewCell` class

**Objcective C**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib() {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    UIView *selectedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [self bounds]];
    [selectedView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor greenColor]];

    [self setSelectedBackgroundView: selectedView];
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let selectedView = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
    selectedView.backgroundColor = .green

    self.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
}
```

Or you can define it directly from your `ViewController` from `collectionView:cellForItemAt` method

**UPD**

As Yerkebulan Abildin has mentioned, this code will work only if you create your `UICollectionViewCell` from nib. If you create it from code, you can define `selectedBackgroundView` in `init` method (cause `awakeFromNib` won't call)

Comment: awakeFromNib will not work if it load from init method